# jQuery Ajax wont POST to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I don't know why but jQuery Ajax wont post the data to the url.

```
$('#submit2').on('click', function(){
  var name = $('#name2').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var text = $('#comment2').val();

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "mail/mail.php",
    data: {name: name, email: email, text: text},
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="contactus">
  <input id="name2" type="text" placeholder="NAAM"/>
  <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL"/>
  <textarea id="comment2" type="text" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="verzenden" id="submit2">
</div>
```

I want to do it without using forms.

Comment: `$('#name2').val()` instead of `.var`?

Comment: You are using the same name of the vars, when you get the inputs values and when you asing the values to your data

Comment: You have a typo in `$('#name2').var` and the 2 following lines, it should be `.val`

Comment: @juanbits Ty! had a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` to get the value and not `.var`. `var` is to define a variable like you did for name, email and text.

change this

```
  var name = $('#name2').var;
```

to

```
  var name = $('#name2').val();
```

Do the same for all the three variables.

Comment: Now it only sends #email, the other two aren't send.

Comment: @Dogantr Code looks good. Just that you don't need `type=text` in `textarea` element. Also make sure there are no other elements with id as `name2` and `comment2`. Id has to be unique. I am guessing you have more than 1 elements with the same ID

Comment: Ty i had a typo with the $_POST

Comment: @Dogantr dont' forget to accept an answer if it solved your issue.